# Extend UITextView height so that it fits all the content inside a JSON string (iOS7)

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking

I have a UITextView inside my Collection View Cell thats linked to a JSON String ("body") that I'm parsing with AFNetworking. The text inside that string varies (each of my "posts" has different information). I want my UITextView to extend based on the content inside my String so that all of the text shows up.

**Collection View Cell**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic, readonly) IBOutlet UITextView *body;
```

**View Controller:**

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    PostCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *newPostDictionary = [self.singlePost objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.body.text = [newPostDictionary objectForKey:@"caption"];

    NSLog(@"@");

    return cell;
}
```

I tried adding this code inside my View Controller but that did nothing.

```
- (CGFloat)textViewHeightForAttributedText: (NSAttributedString*)text andWidth: (CGFloat)width {
    UITextView *calculationView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    [calculationView setAttributedText:text];
    CGSize size = [calculationView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX)];
    return size.height;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get the size of any text, you should use the method of NSString: `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:` you pass as parameters the font and the maximum size can be reached from that text.

```
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize] constrainedToSize:maxSize];
```

Comment: according to the question, he wants the UITextView to extent, not the content to shrink.

Comment: He want to resize UITextView, with this he obtain the size of the text and can change height of the textview.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:` to get size of string

If you're on iOS7 use `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` instead (`sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:` is deprecated on iOS7)

Comment: you may try with subclassing `UICollectionViewCell` manually adding your UITextView there, and in `layoutSubviews` method setting that textView frame to result of `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` method

Answer (score 0):

Set UITextView frame to be the same as the content inside it:

```
CGRect frame = _textView.frame;
frame.size.height = _textView.contentSize.height;
_textView.frame = frame;
```